# Cant fetch post from SQL Database

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello i'm trying to get the data from my sql with is the id,    post_author,    post_date,  post_content,   post_title &    post_status

Right now my basic for the post.php is this

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
$post = "";
$id = 1;
// ^'will be using $_GET['id'] to get current post
find_post_by_id($id, $public=true);
?>
<?php include("../../includes/layouts/header.php") ?>

<div class="container post">
    <h1><?php echo htmlentities($post["post_title"]); ?></h1>
    <p>Auther & postdate n time</p>
    <hr class="hrpost">
    <div class="content">
        Content in form of the text
    </div>
</div>

<?php include("../../includes/layouts/footer.php") ?>
```

and in functions.php i have this

```
function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
}

function find_post_by_id($post_id, $public=true) {
    global $connection;

    $safe_page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $post_id);

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM posts ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = {$safe_page_id} ";
    if ($public) {
        $query .= "AND post_status = \"publish\" ";
    }
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $post_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($post_set);
    if($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post_set)) {
        return $post;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then when im trying to get it its saying ->

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'post_title' in D line 13.

Why do it do that and how to i fix it ???

Comment: $post doesn't seem to be an array, can be returning null. try var_dump($post);

Comment: Sorry it was ment to be mysqli_fetch_assoc i edited @Ekin :)

And if it it where u i put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you're looking for.

```
$post = find_post_by_id($id, $public=true);
```

If the query does not return what you need then make sure you print out or log the query. Then run that query on your mysql console to double check it actually returns something.

Comment: Dude Thanks ! 

It returned TEST :) as the post title whas thanks alot @timhysniu